# Displaying clusters of points in a Flutter application

Tags: google-maps, flutter

My application is requiring to display cluster of points.
I do not find any flutter package allowing this feature. 
Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Clustering for Flutter Google Maps**

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/clustering_google_maps